# Нужно записать массив в файл

Tags: php, массивы, файлы

Есть массив, который очень быстро пополняется значениями и из него удаляются все значения. Мне нужно что бы в определенный момент(я сам знаю в какой), ВСЕ значения массива записывались в файл ПОСЛЕ ПРЕДЫДУЩИХ ЗАПИСЕЙ. Тоесть, уже сохранено например

```
0.1;asdfg
0.2;qwert
0.3;zxcvb
```

А после следующего заполнения будет уже

```
0.1;asdfg
0.2;qwert
0.3;zxcvb
0.4;poiuy
0.5;lkjhg
0.6;mnbvc
```

Если что, буквы и числа будут другие, это просто пример.

И нужно что бы я мог читать этот файл построчно.

Comment: А почему именно массив, а не база данных

Comment: @АнтонСкородумов, я делаю на чистом PHP и базы данных мне тут не нужны.

Comment: тогда тут все ответы на Ваши вопросы http://php.net/manual/ru/function.fopen.php
http://php.net/manual/ru/function.fwrite.php
хотя Вам сразу нужно считать существующие, а потом записать недостающие

Comment: Решили вопрос ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Если уж оно так сильно надо хранить в массиве, то лучше хранить в виде json. Плюсов много. Из самых очевидных - можно легко хранить многомерные массивы, нет нужды перебирать каждое значение в цикле и т.п.

```
$file = "test.txt";
$test_data = array(
    'ttt' => '565t',
    'dfdf' => 'dfgt55',
    'ваа' => array(
        'ddf' => 5, 
    ),
    //другие данные
);
file_put_contents($file, json_encode($test_data, JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE)); //преобразуем в json представление

//json to array
$array=json_decode(file_get_contents($file));
```

Comment: Выдает ошибку:
 
PHP Warning:  fopen(mytext.txt): failed to open stream: Permission denied in source_file.php on line 41
PHP Warning:  fwrite() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given in source_file.php on line 42
PHP Warning:  fclose() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given in source_file.php on line 44

Comment: путь до файла в переменной $file пропишите правильно. И закройте этот файл, если он у вас открыт

Comment: всмысле правильно? Прописать полный путь?

Comment: Смотря что вы там делаете. Создайте пустой файл `test.txt` в той же директории, где и скрипт лежит с кодом php. И тогда можно ничего не менять. Ошибка ваша говорит о том, что не смог php получить доступ к файлу. Если не поможет, то будет дальше смотреть. Возможно локальный сервер не так настроен.

Answer (score 0):

В простейшем варианте можно использовать пару `file()`/`file_put_contents()`;

```php
// прочитать массив из файла
$filename = 'text.txt';
$array = file($filename); // элементы массива содержат переводы строк!

//записать массив в файл, перезаписав его содержимое
file_put_contents($filename, $array); // элементы массива должны содержать переводы строк

// дописать массив к существующему в файле
file_put_contents($filename, $array, FILE_APPEND); // должны быть переводы строк
```

Если элементы массива не содержат переводы строк, то либо добавить их перед записью, либо записывать по одной строке в цикле, как показано в соседнем ответе

Answer (score -1):

Примерно так, я думаю (код не запускал, но вроде ошибок нет):

```
$file = "data/file.txt";
$arr = ['aa' => 'bb', 'cc' => 'dd', /* пример данных */];

$fh = fopen($file, 'w+'); // + означает "дописать с конец файла"
foreach ($arr as $key=>$value) {
   fwrite($fh, "$key;$value\n");
}
fclose($fh);
```

Comment: Теже самые ошибки.

Comment: Ок, я вижу вам уже объяснини в другом ответе, что проблема просто с именем файла.